# Improve the levenstein distance comparison on text columns in postgresql using index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, full-text-search, levenshtein-distance

I have a table where each row has two columns of names representing an intersection. there is a second table, in which each row presenting one street of an intersection related by an object id. What I want to do, search each row of my first table in the second table and find the objectid of an intersection where both names are matched. the [function](https://github.com/CityofToronto/bdit_data-sources/blob/master/gis/text_to_centreline/sql/helper_functions/function-get_intersection_id.sql) for matching, uses levenstein distance and compare each of two names from first table  with all the names from the second one and in cases they are matched with two records with the same objectid, it returns the info. and then I join it with the third table to get all the information for each objectid. The function uses the second table.

```
SELECT a.*,
int_func[3] as int_id_func,
intersec5,
b.longitude as int_long,
b.latitude as int_lat,
b.geom
FROM 
(
    SELECT ft.*, gis._get_intersection_id(ft.stname1,   ft.stname2, 0) AS int_func
    FROM first_table  AS ft
) as a
JOIN third_table b ON a.int_func[3] = b.int_id
```

My question is what would be the best index option. Whatever that I used so far, is not working. when I use Explain, it has not used any indices.

I also noticed this [solution](https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/1535819), where it applies GIST on the function,

```
CREATE INDEX lev_idx ON table1 USING GIST(levenshtein(string,'ciao'));
```

But I was not sure, how I can change the index second parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any meaningful way in which Levenshtein can be indexed.

In the example you show, the 2nd parameter cannot be changed (without building a whole new index).  That is why this is not a *meaningful* way to index Levenshtein--you can't freely use arbitrary parameters.

You could look into using the distance operator defined by pg_trgm instead.  It can be indexed, although it isn't clear how useful the index would be in this situation where the strings are of rather unequal length.

You might get better results if you gave example data, rather than just tossing us a query with neither table structure nor the data.

Comment: thanks, I used the trigram similarity to improve the performance.